# Symfony cannot authenticate

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

I am following the [Symfony cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html) and in "avoiding common pitfalls" it says:

> Also, if your firewall does not allow for anonymous users (no `anonymous` key), you'll need to create a special firewall that allows anonymous users for the login page
>
> ```
> firewalls:
>     # order matters! This must be before the ^/ firewall
>     login_firewall:
>         pattern:   ^/login$
>         anonymous: ~
>     secured_area:
>         pattern:    ^/
>         form_login: ~
> ```

So I implemented my `security.yml` file as following:

```
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    ryan:
                        password: pass1
                        roles: ROLE_USER
                    admin:
                        password: pass2
                        roles: ROLE_ADMIN

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login_firewall:
            anonymous: ~
            pattern: ^/login$
            context: foo

        main:
            pattern: ^/

            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login
                default_target_path: /secret

            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: homepage

            context: foo

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/secret, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

The problem is that whenever I try to login I get redirected to the login page and I never get authenticated. I also tried to share the context between the two firewalls (i.e. they are using the same `context`), but with no positive effect.

What is wrong with this configuration?

### EDIT:

This is my `login.html.twig` template:

```
<html>
    <body>
        {% if error %}
            <div>{{ error.messageKey | trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
        {% endif %}

        <form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

            <button type="submit" >Login</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show your `login.html.twig`? There they have a comment saying: `If you want to control the URL the user
        is redirected to on success (more details below)
        <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />`

Comment: Yeah sure. Please note however that I have no `_target_path` inside my twig template. Instead I set  `default_target_path: /secret` inside `main: form_login` firewall.

Comment: Just try put this line `<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/secret" />` in your `<form>`

Comment: I've already tried to do like this, but with no luck. Moreover in Symfony's built-in profiler I see that I'm always logged in as `anon.`

Comment: Moreover even if I delete all the `access_control` lines, I keep getting the same behavior, so I think that there's something wrong with the firewalls themselves

Comment: or with the encoders: have a look here as example how they put the encoders to plaintext http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html, also do not forget to clear cache after changes in .yml files

Comment: I don't exactly know why, but by placing the `form_login` **both** inside `main` and inside `login_firewall` it lets me authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why (if someone does, they are welcome to add another answer) but if I place the `form_login` element **both** inside `login_firewall` and inside `main`, then it lets the user authenticate.

In other words the working `security.xml` configuration is:

(**edit**: the `main -> form_login` can be `null` as well)

```
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    ryan:
                        password: pass1
                        roles: ROLE_USER
                    admin:
                        password: pass2
                        roles: ROLE_ADMIN

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login_firewall:
            anonymous: ~
            pattern: ^/(login|logout)?$
            context: foo

            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login

            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: homepage

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login: ~
            context: foo

    access_control:
        - { path: /(login|logout)?$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: /secret, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```